# Map Reduce Wrong Output/How to Subtract in reducer. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Tags: loops, mapreduce, iterator, output, reducers

I'm trying to find the range/difference between two values from a given key (from mapper).

I want to do TMAX minus TMIN (TMAX - TMIN), however i'm getting minus results and I don't know a way around it.

How do i find out the Range/Difference between two values formed from the key.

Sample Dataset

Station Date(YYYYMMDD) element temperature flag1 flag2 othervalue

i only need station, date(key), element and temperature(value) from dataset

```
USW00003889,20180101,TMAX,122,7,1700
USW00003889,20180101,TMIN,-67,7,1700
UK000056225,20180101,TOBS,56,7,1700
UK000056225,20180101,PRCP,0,7,1700
UK000056225,20180101,SNOW,0,7
USC00264341,20180101,SNWD,0,7,1700
USC00256837,20180101,PRCP,0,7,800
UK000056225,20180101,SNOW,0,7
UK000056225,20180101,SNWD,0,7,800
USW00003889,20180102,TMAX,12,E
USW00003889,20180102,TMIN,3,E
UK000056225,20180101,PRCP,42,E
SWE00138880,20180101,PRCP,50,E
UK000056225,20180101,PRCP,0,a
USC00256480,20180101,PRCP,0,7,700
USC00256480,20180101,SNOW,0,7
USC00256480,20180101,SNWD,0,7,700
SWE00138880,20180103,TMAX,-228,7,800
SWE00138880,20180103,TMIN,-328,7,800
USC00247342,20180101,PRCP,0,7,800
UK000056225,20180101,SNOW,0,7
SWE00137764,20180101,PRCP,63,E
UK000056225,20180101,SNWD,0,E
USW00003889,20180104,TMAX,-43,W
USW00003889,20180104,TMIN,-177,W
```

```
Mapper Output Example
20180102,TMAX, 12
20180102,TMIN, 3
```

```
What I Want to do
20180102, 12 - 3
```

```
Reducer Current Output
20180102, -9
```

```
Reducer Desired Output
20180102, 9
```

```
            public static class MaxMinReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

             public IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
              public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws 
                    IOException, InterruptedException {

                int value1 = 0;
                int value2 = 0;
                int differenceResult = 0;
                Iterator<IntWritable> iterator = values.iterator();


                while (values.iterator().hasNext()) {


                    if(value1 != 0){

                        value2 = iterator.next().get();
                        break;

                    } else {

                        value1 = iterator.next().get();
                    }

                    differenceResult = value1 - value2;     

                }

                differenceResult = value1 - value2;
                result.set(differenceResult);
                context.write(key, result);

              }

        }
```

UPDATE 1: I've tried it this way but im getting Error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` .. Why ?

```
        public static class MaxMinReducer
            extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

              public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                String result = "";  
                int value1 = 0;
                int value2 = 0;
                int differenceResult = 0;
                String finalVal = "";   

                     for (Text val : values) {

                         finalVal = finalVal.concat(val.toString()).concat(",");

                     } 


                     finalVal = finalVal.substring(0,finalVal.length()-1);
                     String[] diffValues = finalVal.split(",");
                     value1 = Integer.parseInt(diffValues[1]);
                     value2 = Integer.parseInt(diffValues[0]);
                     differenceResult = value1 - value2;             
                     result = Integer.toString(differenceResult);

                     context.write(key, new Text(result));

              }

        }
```

Comment: You never bothered to compute the min or max, so what is it that you think you are subtracting? As I already pointed out, you can't take the difference of a set. It doesn't make sense. Yet, you are still trying to do that... Min and max are not 2 elements of your data. They are statistics that you need to compute from the entire set.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by this, but I've tried it another way but I'm getting an IndexOutOfBounds problem, please check that out.

Comment: It's because you create a new array and then witlessly assume that it has 2 elements. Apparently, it does not.

Comment: Ok, I'm tryng to think about it and so do I create these methods within the loop to get the values to compute ?

Comment: You can't create methods within a loop. You create them inside your class. Make a new class with a new main method for a program whose only purpose is to demonstrate that you created the methods correctly.